# SQL query - select usernames and sum their row

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
SELECT username FROM paymentValue
```

I can sum `paymentValue` for username like

```
SELECT username, SUM(paymentValue) WHERE username = 'john'
```

But how to select sums for all usernames to get return like:
john, 146
marry, 3456
anna, 2043

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the 'group by' clause

```
select username, sum(paymentvalue) as sumofpayments from thetable
group by username
```

Comment: And how instad of counting sum of single value, return sum of records? Like 1000$ in x transactions

Comment: select sum(paymentValue)as totalPayments from table

Comment: Not sure what you mean,  This will give a sum of all the paymentvalue values for john,  then steve, then anne, then sarah and so on

Comment: Sounds like he wants it both ways now.  Total by person and total sum of all.  Hard to follow this question

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT username, SUM(paymentValue) 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY username
```

to JOIN with another table

```
SELECT username, SUM(paymentValue) 
FROM TableName INNER JOIN SecondTable
ON TableName.RefrencingColumn = SecondTable.RefrencingColumn  
WHERE username = 'john'
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: And how to join it with another query that sums same data from other table?

Comment: It would be pointless grouping by username if you're only selecting rows with one username (john)

Comment: #1052 - Column 'username' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Yes True @MrVimes but it would give OP the understanding of a very basic syntax.

Comment: @Ultra use `TableName.ColumnName` , field list is ambiguous means you have a column with same name in both tables, you need to use two part name for your column to tell sql from which table you want that column.

Comment: 'two part name' - Like?

Comment: Two part name means  `TableName.ColumnName`

Comment: And how to alias this in given query?

Comment: @Ultra In your FROM Clause you can do something like FROM TableName AS A , `A` will be your table Alias in this case.

Comment: ultra you would do something like this
select a.username,sum(a.paymentValue) from tablename a inner join secondTable b on a.column = b.column where a.username = 'John' group by a.username

Answer (score 0):

```
select username,
       sum(paymentValue) as Payments
from paymentValue
group by username
```